# check if the folder does not exist or is not accessible

Tags: c#, directory, network-programming

Within my code I have this function that goes through a list in which there are files that are not detected locally but are registered in the database and it deletes the files from the database and later the folders in another foreach.

> Since the variables are in Spanish, I will explain to you what they are.
>
> `codigoDestinoTuple` = a Tuple in which item 1 is the file code and item 2 is the directory
>
> `codigo` = file code / `destino` = file directory

```
foreach (Tuple<int, string> codigoDestinoTuple in codDestinoPDF){
    try{
        int codigo = codigoDestinoTuple.Item1;
        string destino = codigoDestinoTuple.Item2;

        //I think the check should go here before playing with the folders
        //because from this point on the folders stored in the list "carpetas"
        //are the ones that I will delete

        // Get list of folders from path
        List<string> carpetas = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(destino).Split(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).ToList();

       // Rebuild path without file name
       string carpetaSinArchivo = string.Join(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), carpetas);

       // Add the route to the unique list if it is not already present
       if (!rutasUnicas.Contains(carpetaSinArchivo)){
           rutasUnicas.Add(carpetaSinArchivo);
       }

//the code continues with irrelevant information......
```

My problem comes in the event that the file is on a drive associated with the cloud (For example, Google Drive creates the E:// drive) if the folder fails or the cloud system fails, the program will detect the folder or the file as non-existent and will delete all files registered in the database

Is there any way to check if the folder does not exist (continue the code as before) or if the folder cannot be accessed either due to a connection failure at the source of the folder or because the user does not have access to that folder (so that if Is that the case, it skips that turn of the loop)?

January 26: I added this to my code, I don't know if this is the solution, I have added a check to see if the directory exists or not since I will work with existing and non-existent directories and with this I will prevent the catch from being triggered if the directory does not exist

```
foreach (Tuple<int, string> codigoDestinoTuple in codDestinoPDF)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("borrar_autentico. 6º try ");
        int codigo = codigoDestinoTuple.Item1;
        string destino = codigoDestinoTuple.Item2;

        // Check if the directory exists
        if (!Directory.Exists(destino))
        {
            // We add the non-existing directories to the list
            Console.WriteLine($"borrar_autentico. El directorio no existe: {destino}. Agregándolo a la lista de carpetasNoExistentes.");
            carpetas.Add(destino);
        }

        // Try to access the directory
        try
        {     
            // If we get here, we can access the directory
            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(destino);

            // We add the existing directories to the list
            carpetas.Add(destino);

            // Here continues the code with which I delete files whose paths are in the 'carpetas' list...
        }

        // TRY TO SEE IF THIS CATCHES CLOUD UNITS
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            // Handle access denied exception (we skip deletion)
            Console.WriteLine($"borrar_autentico. Acceso denegado al intentar acceder a la carpeta: {destino}. Se omite el borrado.");

            // Move to next element in the loop
            continue;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // I handle the exception
        Console.WriteLine($"borrar_autentico. Error al procesar un registro: {ex.Message}, haciendo Rollback...\n");
        tr.Rollback();
        return;
    }
}
```